# Execute *nix find command using java code

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to execute a find command using java code.  I did the following:

```
sysCommand = "find . -name '*out*' > file1"

Runtime runtimeObj = Runtime.getRuntime();

try {
    Process processObj = runtimeObj.exec(sysCommand);
    processObj.waitFor();
    ...
```

This Linux command is executed when I use command line but fails in Java, why?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am unable to execute this command by using java code

Answer (score 1):

This question is probably a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062595/runtime-exec-not-running-the-find-command) or a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704889/java-execute-command-line-program-find-returns-error).

- Anyway, you could use [File.list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29), providing a Filter on the type
  of files you want.  You could call it recursively to get all sub-directories.  I don't love this answer.  You would think there is a simpler way.
- A friend of mine recommended [Commons-Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) from Apache for running a command.  It allows you to use a time out on the command.  He recommended it because Runtime can have issues with large stdout and stderr.

Comment: Would File.list work on sub directories . Like If I have files in multiple sub directories then would it work.

Comment: No I don't think it will find sub-dirs.  There has got to be a better way than [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008043/list-all-files-from-directories-and-subdirectories-in-java).

Comment: I've included an answer that will search sub-directories using File.listFiles. I would recommend using `ProcessBuilder`, but yes, there are risks to making a sub-process in that some operating systems will hang the process if the standard output/error buffer fills. You must consume those streams.

Comment: +1 because the second "duplicate" link has a helpful question body.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not allowable to use any form of piping operator in `Runtime.exec`. If you want to move the results to a file, you will have to do that part in Java through `Process.getInputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in doing this in Java then you will want to do something like this:

```
public void find(File startDirectory, FileFilter filter, List<File> matches) {
    File[] files = startDirectory.listFiles(filter);
    for (File file:files) {
        if(file.isDirectory()) {
            find(file, filter, matches);
        } else {
            matches.add(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need but write the `FileFilter` to accept directories and files that match your pattern.